# Validation loss increasing

Tags: python, neural-network, deep-learning

I am trying to solve dogs vs cats problem in kaggle with my numpy neural network.

Validation loss

[image: Validation loss graph]

Training loss

[image: training loss graph]

My training loss decreases well but the validation loss increases, so my model is definitely overfitting.
I used two hidden layers with size 125, 50. I used learning rate of 0.075 ran the model with 600 iterations.

I also tried using regularization with lambda = 0.01 or 0.03, but still didn't help.

Any solutions to this problem?

Comment: I also used 100 images per each class. Would this be a problem?

Comment: How do you expect to get help if we don't know what you did?

Answer (score 10):

Add Dropout to each layer with a dropout-probability of .5. See how it influences the validation error and if your training error won’t go deeper than a specific point, either decrease the probability to .3 or sequentially remove it from the first layers. It’s a bit of try-and-error here.

I guess you mean L2 regularization (weight-decay) with lamda. Nowadays, nets usually use dropout and a very small L2 like 0.0005. The L2 causes the weights to be close to zero and prevents them from exploding. Dropout is a better regulizer because it randomly drops nodes during training which causes some sort of specialization.

Good luck.

Comment: Did adding dropout help?